# I can't manage to leave the organization Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops

I click the 'Leave' button. To leave a popup page appears. I approve of saying leave. The page reloads and the organization is standing there. I can't manage to leave the organization.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/faq-user-and-permissions-management?view=azure-devops#leave-your-organization

Comment: Have you accessed the organization before? Have you tried clear the browser cache? You may open the browser in a new Inprivate/incognito session and try again. And if the issue persists, try to capture a fiddler trace to see whether there is any useful information.

Comment: @CeceDong-MSFT Thank you for your answer. However, I cannot get rid of this organization in any way.

Comment: Are you able to contact the administrator to remove you from the organization? If you can not contact with the organization, please open a case on [developercommunity](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/post.html?space=21) to get help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ironically, you need to be a valid member of the organization to authenticate to it, and thus leave it....

If someone disabled your account (for example), then you can not authenticate and can not leave.... you need to get a valid administrator there to remove you...

[As a consultant this happens to me all the time. Sometimes they do not respond. I am shown as a member of multiple organizations that I have not been able to access for years]

Comment: I understand. This is a normal case. :) Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

None of the above steps worked, it was stuck in an infinite loop on pressing the Leave button and it won't let me leave the organization

Finally opened a ticket with MS support, and over the call with them, even they were surprised why this is happening. They finally came back after consulting with their 'Senior Engineer' and told me -

to try the below link to remove the tenant by adding tenant **GUID** which you wanted to remove and provide us the screen shot, if there is any error message.

**https://myaccount.microsoft.com?tenantid=GUID** to be removed

Went to that link, gettint the GUID from portal.azure.com=>Active Directory=>Manage Tenants=>Get GUID/Organization ID from there

Once then in above link for myaccount, goto Organization page and select Leave. It worked!! :)